# Building a binary tree given the postorder and inorder traversals

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

Following [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/) link, I modified the code to build a binary tree given the postorder and inorder traversals. But the output seems to generate some junk values. I couldn't understand where I have gone wrong. A preorder traversal has root at the beginning and a postorder traversal has root at the end. Using that logic, I modified the code. As follows:

```
struct tree* buildTree2(char in[], char post[], int inStrt, int inEnd)
{
    static int postIndex = sizeof(post)/sizeof(post[0]) - 1; //postorder index
    if(inStrt > inEnd) 
        return NULL;
    struct tree* tNode = newNode(post[postIndex--]);
    if(inStrt == inEnd)
        return tNode;
    else
    {
        int inIndex = search(in, inStrt, inEnd, tNode->data);
        tNode->left = buildTree(in, post, inStrt, inIndex-1); 
        tNode->right = buildTree(in, post, inIndex+1, inEnd);
        return tNode;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 The inorder traversal of the build tree (using preorder traversal) is : D B E A F C 
 The inorder traversal of the build tree (using postorder traversal) is : D B I R O  7 = R N T V _ G D X  t u o . a / .
```

Modified code:

```
struct tree* buildTree2(char in[], char post[], int inStrt, int inEnd, int postIndex)
{
    //printf("\n %d ",postIndex);
    if(inStrt > inEnd) //termination condition for buildTree(in, post, inIndex+1, inEnd)
        return NULL;
    struct tree* tNode = newNode(post[postIndex--]);
    //check if node has children
    if(inStrt == inEnd)
        return tNode;
    else
    {
        //get the index of the postorder variable in the inorder traversal
        int inIndex = search(in, inStrt, inEnd, tNode->data);
        //Recursively build the tree
        tNode->left = buildTree2(in, post, inStrt, inIndex-1, postIndex); 
          //The inIndex value points to the tNode. So less than that is left sub tree and more than that is the right sub tree
        tNode->right = buildTree2(in, post, inIndex+1, inEnd, postIndex);
        return tNode;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The inorder traversal of the build tree (using preorder traversal) is : D B E A F C 
 The inorder traversal of the build tree (using postorder traversal) is : E B E
```

Comment: `sizeof(post)/sizeof(post[0])`. This doesn't do what you think is does (print it and see). C is not Java (just a friendly reminder).

Comment: I tried with hard coding the input (the last index in the array), but still it doesn't work @n.m.

Comment: Fix the first bug, then we can concentrate on the next one.

Comment: @n.m. I have fixed the bug. But the issue remains the same.

Comment: OK having postindex as an argument is much better than as a static ;) Another problem here is that preorder and postorder are not mirror images of each other. Preorder goes "root, left, right" and postorder is "left, right, root". That is, what comes after the root in preorder is the left subtree, but what comes before the root in postorder is the *right* subtree.

Answer (score 0):

```
node<int> * consTree(int * post, int * in, int postS, int postE, int inS, int inE){
    if(postS > postE)
    return NULL;

    int rootdata = post[postE];
    int indexI = -1;
    for(int i = inS; i <= inE; i++){
        if(rootdata == in[i]){
            indexI = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    int lpostS = postS;
    int linS = inS;
    int linE = indexI - 1;
    int lpostE = postS + indexI - inS - 1;
    int rpostS = postS + indexI - inS;
    int rpostE = postE - 1;
    int rinS = indexI + 1;
    int rinE = inE;

    node<int> * root = new node<int>(rootdata);
    root -> left = consTree(post,in,lpostS,lpostE,linS,linE);
    root -> right = consTree(post,in,rpostS,rpostE,rinS,rinE);
    return root;
}
```

Basically you need to think , when the right order both traversal are passed in the recursive call the array passed remain same just the indexes are changed..in that case let say i have pass in right order traversal (arr,6,9) so the changes should be made between that indexes only.. not from the 0(starting index of array)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).